# Using Node.js to access azure tablestorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, typescript, azure-storage

I've been trying to write a typescript application in visual studio using node.js to store and access data in an azure table store.

I've been having some trouble with the tutorials I've found. I've yet to get one to work properly.

I have Node installed on my machine and a tablestore set up in azure.

I'm not exactly sure what needs to be done in visual studio to get all the necessary packages/modules/whatever installed correctly.

Many of the tutorials I've read have used express.js and or have "npm install"ed things and while I have no issue running the commands I don't really understand what I'm installing.

---

**tl;dr** I want to make an html page where I can submit and display items to/from azure table store using node.js, typescript, and visual studio

**Also:** I'd be willing to drop the typescript in favor of javascript if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this one (I'm assuming you probably tried this as well)

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-use-table-storage-web-site/

To boil it down to just what you need in javascript ...

1.Create the table in Azure portal with appropriate data/partition key.

2.NPM necessary packages: azure, async

3.Add the following to app.js (change table_Users to whatever you want to name your table):

```
var azure = require('azure');

var storageClient = azure.createTableService("<accountname>", "<accountkey>");

storageClient.createTableIfNotExists("table_Users", function tableCreated(error) {
   if(error) {
       throw error;
   }
});

var query = azure.TableQuery
      .select()
      .from("<tablename>");
      //.where('completed eq ?', false); put criteria here.

storageClient.queryEntities(query, function entitiesQueried(error, result) {
    // do what you want with result
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but I haven't quite gotten it yet. When I run my code I get TableQuery() has no method 'select'. Also what is the tablename? I am currently using the accountname as the tablename. is that causing my issue?

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake above, you'd want to do require('azure'); and get that through npm instead. I'll make the necessary edit.  As far as the table thing goes, that's the name of the table you want out in azure, I'll update the answer for more info.

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial looks like it might be based on the old Node storage package. We have recently posted a new storage library for node - which can be found here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/azure-storage. Also take a look at the following Getting Started to help get you up and running: [Store structured data with Table storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-table-storage/).

I will follow up tomorrow to see what we can do to either remove the old tutorial or get it updated. Let me know if anyone wants to volunteer to update the old tutorial!

Jason